# A lot of vs. excess

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Question: Should we drink a lot of water?

Answer 1: Since drinking a lot of water can reduce sodium, we should drink adequately.

Answer 2: Yes, drinking a lot of water can improve digestion.

Neither "a lot of" nor "excess" can be calculated. In answer number 1 I suppose a lot exceeds the prescribed amount. While in answer number 2 I suppose you can drink a lot without exceeding the prescribed amount.

Which phrase is correct in the given context?

Comment: The difference in meaning between ***a lot*** (a large amount, which could be either good, bad, or neutral) and ***an excess*** (too much, *always* a bad thing) should be obvious from any dictionary. Armed with that information, just use the one that has the meaning *you* want for your context. And remember the Golden Rule: *All things in moderation (nothing **in excess**).*

Comment: Why are you asking about excess?? Excess means too much.

Comment: Excess here mean when 'a lot' amount exceed the adequate amount .

Comment: In your first sentence, there's no indication that "a lot" would be excess. In fact, you are almost suggesting that "a lot" is "adequate". It's rare for "a lot" to mean excess. It typically just means quite a bit without imposing a positive or negative connotation.

Comment: *"A lot exceeds the prescribed amount*." There is no prescribed amount in the sentence. Nothing has been said one way or the other about *a lot* being too much or the right amount. In fact, it's even possible to construct a sentence where *a lot* means *too little*.